# "Была не была!"

Tags: синтаксис

> Была не была!

Скажите, пожалуйста, как надо рассматривать это предложение. Нашла информацию о том, что это устойчивое выражение. Интересно почему глагол имеет женскую форму? Синтаксически это можно считать как простое предложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**БЫЛА НЕ БЫЛА, междометие.** Выделяется знаками препинания или оформляется **как отдельное предложение-реплика.**

Думал-думал, насмелился: «Была не была, сделаю, как она велела». П. Бажов, Медной горы хозяйка. Гришка хотел было отказаться, но потом с отчаянием решил: «Эх, была не была, вывезу!». Г. Белых, Л. Пантелеев, Республика ШКИД. Была не была! Женюсь! [https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/80/была_не_была](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/80/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0)

У Даля: **Была не была (на удачу), куда ни шла. Была не была — катай с плеча.**

https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/539366.html

Тот, кто рискует, надеется на удачу **(ж.род).**

**Смысл можно понять так.**

Рискну, поставлю **на удачу**, куда бы она ни пошла.

Эх, была не была, бросаю жребий (с размаху, с плеча), отдаю себя **в руки судьбы** **(ж.р.)** и готов принять ее любое решение.

Comment: Ответ, ничего не добавляющий к предыдущему, пестрящий ненужными подробностями, и данный лишь для того, чтобы перебить предыдущий ответ длиной. Как насчет женского рода в "была не была"?!

Comment: У Даля говорится про удачу. это сущ. ж.р.

Comment: Я бы написал **наудачу** слитно (хотя во времена Даля или ранее допускались разные варианты написания, даже через дефис). И во втором слове ответа опечатка.

Comment: Из современной орфографии: идти наудачу (наречие) - надеяться на удачу (сущ). Наудачу она свернула в сумрачный коридор и замерла. [Михаил Елизаров. Pasternak (2003)] Теперь ― только ползти и надеяться на удачу. [Михаил Тырин. «Будет немножечко больно» (2014)]

Comment: Да, и я думаю, что у Даля "была не была" синонимично именно наречию "наудачу", которое стоит в скобках с целью пояснения. В современном издании четырёхтомника Даля написано слитно. Но по разным изданиям разнобой.

Comment: Действовать наудачу - слитно. Заговор на удачу - раздельно. Рассчитывать на удачу, положиться на удачу  - раздельно. Не знаю, нужно ли править Даля.

Comment: Niemand  "Как насчет женского рода в "была не была"?! – Niemand 23 фев в 14:43"  А просто звучит хорошо, красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Это просто междометие. Ну, бывают предложения, состоящие из одного междометия, например "Здравствуйте" ("Привет!"), или "Пока", или "Ни пуха ни пера" и т.п.

Вот насчет женского рода глагола сказать не могу. )